# JWT authentication for django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a very interesting issue. We have built couple of apis using django rest framework. These apis are consumed by frontend designed using React. We use SAML withe sessions to manage the authentication process.This SAML authentication is handled by a django middleware.

Now I have a requirement to make some of these apis accessible to a different domain, where their backend would call our apis programmatically. So I need to give auth details to them for them to able to access it.

Since SAML is enabled here, how do I able to set the authentication using JWT and give them the tokens?

The saml middleware code looks like this,

```
class SamlMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_anonymous and 'samlUserdata' in request.session:

            data = request.session['samlUserdata']['mail'][0]
            if data is not None:
                try:
                    email=data
                    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=data.split("@")[0],
                                                    email=data)
                login(request,user)
                request.session.set_expiry(settings.SESSION_EXPIRY)
        elif not settings.DEBUG and  'samlUserdata' not in request.session \
                and not request.get_full_path().startswith('/admin'):
            if not request.path == settings.REDIRECT_LOGIN_URL and not request.path == REDIRECT_LOGOUT_URL and \
                        not request.path == '/saml':
                        return redirect(settings.REDIRECT_LOGIN_URL)

       response = self.get_response(request)
             
            request.session.set_expiry(settings.SESSION_EXPIRY)
   

       if request.user.is_authenticated:
        tokens=self.__class__.get_tokens_for_user(self,request,request.user)


        request.session.set_expiry(settings.SESSION_EXPIRY)

    return response

@staticmethod
def get_tokens_for_user(self,request,user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }    
        return response
```

Now for this I am trying to use djangorestframework-simplejwt. But since SAML is used here, I am not sure how do I implement JWT here. Do I have to change something in the above middleware or any other ways?

Comment: How about create the token manually and include it to the response. djangorestframework-simplejwt allows you to create token manually. The rest configuration is as-is.

Comment: @Devious you mean creating a token here in the same middleware and send as a response. The response from the middleware looks something like this, ```HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url=“https://<identity_provider_url/idp/SSO.saml2?SAMLRequest=skjhjaghjghjhasgjhdgajgshgdjagshjg”>”>
```. It basically tells the browser to redirect to idp.